# Is there a way to shuffle a list in python?

Tags: python, random, shuffle

I'm trying to make a simple encryptions using a random abc to convert it
But i'm having a problem with the Random library.

1. Tried using some other answers that people asked on this issue on StackOverflow and none worked...
2. Tried updating pip and tried updating random (which you cannot apparently use pip because the Random library pre-downloaded with python)
   tried the problematic code in python Shell and still the same problem...

```py
import random
def random(st = 'i love cats')
    abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    randomabc = abc
    random.shuffle(randomabc)
    print(randomabc)
```

the expected output is a random order of the ABC
the actual output is an error (the code stops before the print because of the error)

Comment: If you give to your method same naming as imported module, it'd shadow the module.

Comment: `randomabc = list(abc); random.shuffle(randomabc); return "".join(randomabc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you should give your functions names different from python keywords, imported modules, class names, etc. Try to rename your method form `random` to `random_alphabet`.

```
import random

def random_alphabet(st = 'i love cats'):
    pass
```

Comment: This answer still doesn't address the topic of string not being shuffled @AmitKeren!

Answer (score 2):

Since `abc` is a string, which are immutable (you cannot change it in-place) you cannot do it like that.

Instead you have to:

1. split the string into a list of characters.
2. shuffle that list
3. join the character list back into a string

```
import random

abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
ls = list(abc)
random.shuffle(ls)
abc = ''.join(ls)

print(abc)
```

> Example output:
>
> ```
> erbkvownuhcmfljtgqpyiazdxs
> ```

**Also**: Never name your functions or .py files with names clashing with the standard library. In this case your function is the same name as the `random` module, and that is a huge problem.

Comment: `abc.split()` will just likely return a 1 element list which isn't what's wanted... also, `random.shuffle` is an in place operation and returns `None`, so the code is effectively `''.join(None)` which won't work...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot shuffle a `string`, it is an immutable object which cannot be changed once it is assigned.
Instead you need to convert it to a list (A mutable object), shuffle the list via [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) which shuffles the list in-place,  and then convert the list back to the string.

```
import random

abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

#Convert string to list
li = list(abc)

#Shuffle the list inplace
random.shuffle(li)

#Convert list to string
print(''.join(li))
```

The output will be

```
dpfozwhyxalebnqrmstcjvuigk
qgjefyrahobpnxtzmsdkwivlcu
nchkriewsuxdzyjfgvpblomtqa
.....
```

In addition to it, another alternative (a one-liner) is to use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to pick `len(abc)` unique samples, and join all of them in a string (Thanks @JonClements) but it's more suited for a one off reshuffle

```
print(''.join(random.sample(abc, len(abc))))
```

Comment: Thanks @JonClements Updated my answer to note that and referred you as the originator :)

Comment: Wouldn't say it's a good one-liner... it's just an alternative that's not terrible if you're just doing it as a one off shuffle... if you're repeatedly going to be shuffling and yielding results or similar, then having it as a list, then re-shuffling the list is better.